# Creating tuple of letter and its row and column in list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I need to write a function that creates a tuple in the format ('letter', row, col) of all letters in a list of lists. I realized I could combine two functions I've already written to accomplish this. One function I wrote get_letters(lst) extracts all the letters from the list of lists and the other one I wrote extracts the row and column.

There must be a way to combine these two functions to accomplish this goal without creating a new one but I'm not sure how I would do it. Here's the code for these two functions:

```
def get_letters(lst):
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    newlst = []

    for sublist in lst:
        for i in sublist:

            if i in symbols and i not in newlst:
                newlst.append(i)

             #Example output: (1, 0)

    return newlst

def find_letter(letter, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in lst[i]:
            if j == letter:
                return i ,lot[i].index(j)

       #Example output: ['A']

       #New function example output: [('A', 1, 0)]

       #Example input for both above functions: lst2    =   
              #[['.','M','M','H','H'],
               #['A','.','.','.','f'],
               #['B','C','D','.','f']]
```

Comment: `enumerate` will probably do what both functions are currently doing. You should show a sample input and expected output

Comment: Is there a way without enumerate? Just added example input for both functions and the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `enumerate` is definitely the way to go here. Your first function isn't really doing much and the second is not leveraging useful Python functions.

The following snippet will find the first instance of a letter in your list of lists and return its row and column index:

```
def letter_find(letter, lst):
    for y, row in enumerate(lst):
        if letter in row:
            return letter, y, row.index(letter)
```

Used as follows:

```
lot2    =      [['.','M','M','H','H'],
               ['A','.','.','.','f'],
               ['B','C','D','.','f']]

>>> print(letter_find('A', lot2))
('A', 1, 0)
```

Note that this does not check if the input is actually a letter. If you want to only accept a letter, you can add something like this to the top of the function:

```
if not letter.isalpha():
    raise ValueError('Only letters are accepted')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[(letter, i, j) for i, sublist in enumerate(list_of_list) for j, letter in enumerate(sublist) if letter.isalpha()]
```

Is one way to do it with `enumerate`.  If you can't use `enumerate` for some reason, you can just roll your own:

```
def not_enumerate_i_swear(iterable):
    i = 0
    for item in iterable:
        yield (i, item)
        i += 1
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working. I guess I'm actually supposed to return a list of lists of tuples and the tuples are only the first occurrence of each letter and not just one tuple. I can't get the not_enumerate one to function correctly it is returning one tuple with 0 in the first point and every character in the list in the second point.